# Discord.js suggestion command does not log anything when executed

Tags: discord.js

So i made a suggestion command, pretty simple but it just wont work. I already had a const prefix = "."; it still didnt work, it doesnt show anything on the console and the other commands worked too.

My code:

```
const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');  
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();  


if (command === 'suggest'){   
const channel = msg.channel.name === 'suggestions';  

msg.channel.send('Suggestion:\n ' + args.join(' '))  
}     
});
```

I tried doing .suggest, suggest, !suggest nothing happened
EDIT: It does log it now, it didn't yesterday. But the log is an error.

[SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /+ /: Nothing to repeat]

Yes, thats what was showed in the console when i did .suggest

Comment: I can't find `/+ /` in code you showed us, so maybe this error is coming from another part of it?

Comment: /+ / is from the end of const args specifically split(' ');